# Best practices for Mail Unsubscription workflow

Tags: email, security, authentication, html-email, subscription

I am looking to build a workflow to allow users to unsubscribe (opt out) from receiving mails from a service.

There is a fair amount of documentation around user interactions and page content etc. Here are two good links :

[Act On](https://www.act-on.com/blog/15-best-practices-for-email-unsubscribes-with-examples/)

[Return Path](https://blog.returnpath.com/18-ways-to-improve-your-unsubscribe-process-v2/)

I am looking for technical best practices :

1. How to design the URL that takes the user to the unsubscribe page without requiring them to login/authenticate ? What would be the best way to generate a 'key' component to this URL (e.g. //domain.com/optout/{key}) so it allows the backend to retrieve the email/subscription record/etc ?
2. How to prevent somebody else from accessing this link and invoking unsubscription (I understand this might not be possible, but are there any best practices around this) ?
3. It seems that showing the email-address on the unsubscribe page (given #2) would not be a good idea. Looking for confirmation that email-address should not be shown on the unsubscribe page.
4. It seems it is a good practice to allow users to provide feedback and change frequency or selectively opt out of certain features - so one would need to show a form on a page that is not authenticated. Are there any recommendations in terms of implementing this (outside of the usual csrf token checks on form 'posts').

Sorry if this sounds pedestrian, but I am new to this and could not find any good place that covers the design elements for such a workflow : the need to implement this without authenticating the user seems to make it little more intricate. Thanks !

Comment: Not sure if this would be the best way, but my first thought would be to create a long random string to store when an account is created. On the email the unsubscribe would point to https://my-website.com/?unsub_id=<long_random_string>&uid=<user_id> (the UID in order to make it even harder to unsubscribe some random person, as you need to guess both the random string and the username). On the page I would check if the certain unsubscribe ID corresponds to that user and if yes I would let unsubscription.

Comment: Thanks and makes good sense. My concern also ensues from the fact that this link would be transmitted in mails and allowing access to transporters (ISP's et al).

Comment: Then you should probably secure the email. I cannot think of a way that would not require login and at the same time the information is 'public'. If I understood correctly.